# Using a Toggled button to set a href, using mysql and php

Tags: php, html, mysql, toggle

Hy all,
I am new programming on php. Basically in my school project I am sending to my navbar all the names of cities from my database as "city". Those cities are linked to a "name" that send to a respective webpage. For each city you can go for two different page by a toggle button, I mean if the button is on you go for namerent.php, if the button is off you go for name.php. As I see in my code when I click on the toggle button it is going to only one way.

```
<div class="navbar">
<ul>
<li class="current"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
<li><a>Location</a>
<ul>
<li><?php while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2) and $row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result3)) {?><a href="<?php echo utf8_encode($row2["name"]);?>
```

Here when the togBtn changes it should set the correct end of the name of the webpage.

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['togBtn']) AND isset($_POST['on'])){echo "rent.php";}else{ echo ".php";}?>">

<?php echo utf8_encode($row3["city"]);?><?php }?></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Form for a Rounded switch

```
<form method="post" action="index.php">
<label class="switch">
<input type="checkbox" id="togBtn" class="togBtn" method="post">
<div class="slider round" id="btn">
<span class="on" name="on" id="on" value="on">rent</span>
<span class="off" name="off" id="off" value="off">sell</span>
</div>
</label>
</form>
```

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: he is using mysqli_query....mysqli_fetch_array($result2) and $row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result3)

Comment: Don't confuse him he said he was new lol

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to Create A button to switch between 2 pages try this. No need for PHP with this.

Page1

```
 <body>
 <form method="post" action="page2.php">
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="rent"> 
 </form> 
 sale page Content
 </body>
```

Page2

```
<body>
<form method="post"  action="page1.php">
<input type="submit" name="submitb" value="sale">
</form> 
rent page content.
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks. But even if I press the button still going to else statement as always it is false. I believe the problem can be in toggle button.

Comment: Are you trying to make one button swap between the pages and use the checkbox to trigger it?

Comment: I have updated my answer maybe this solves your problem.

Comment: thanks, but the main idea is, I have in my navigation bar about 5 different cities so far, where each city can take you to the sell option page or the rent option page. So in my database I related those cities by names where is the same name of each page of sell option (that is why this ending in '.php'), then I would like to add any character to the end of the name of this city to send the user to the rent option for that city(ending in 'rent.php'). Basically  I want to avoid add to many buttons and build a project a bit more easy to navigate and learn something new.